# Set space between Reference items in Rmarkdown biblography using csl-file

Tags: r, r-markdown, bibtex, xelatex, csl

### I am currently trying to properly format my bibliograpy in an Rmarkdown file while using a csl -file.

When using natbib the spacing between the ref-items works fine, however using a csl file, it doesn't result in a proper spacing.

I dont want to use natbib but csl for several other reasons

Since \setlength\bibitemsep or similar dont work with csl .

#### YAML

```
font-family: Arial
mainfont: Arial
header-includes:
   - \pagenumbering{gobble}
   - \usepackage{caption}
   - \usepackage{float}
   - \captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize,format=hang,labelfont=bf,textfont=it,width=.95\textwidth}
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    includes:
    text-align: justify
    latex_engine: "xelatex"
    number_sections: yes
    fig_caption: yes
    toc: false
geometry: "left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm"
fontsize: 12pt
bibliography: Microt.bib
csl: the-journal-of-cell-biology.csl
linestretch: 1.5
link-citations: yes
editor_options: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: sentence
```

then in the end of the rmd:

````
\```{=tex}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\```

# Literature {.unnumbered}
\singlespacing
````

#### with csl the spaces are to small

[image: cslspacing]

#### with natbib the spaces are fine

`citation_package: natbib` in YAML

[image]

but the entries are too verboose

#### Is there any good solution without studying Latex for weeks and fight with tlmgr,etc?

Comment: Can you make a [mre] in a single file which actually has citations in it to produce a bibliography?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it, in

CSL use:

```
<bibliography entry-spacing = "2" >
```